# How to use regex with pattern matcher against multiple strings?

Tags: java, regex

I'm reading in a list of strings from a `List<String>`.  The strings look like this:

```
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
```

In java, I'd like to build a regex that checks for a pattern like this `(myString/|yourString)` and concatenate that to each of the strings in the list above while doing a pattern match against the lines of a file.

So I do this (the code below is just snippits):

```
String pattern = "(myString/|yourString.)"
private String listAsString;  

private void createListAsStrings() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for(String string : stringList) {
      sb.append(string + "|");  # using the pipe hoping it will do an OR in the regex
   }

   listAsString = sb.toString();
}
```

To build the pattern, I'm trying to do the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern + listAsString);
```

But when I get to running the matcher it doesn't go through each string in the list of strings from my stringbuilder.  And then the last problem is that my last string will contain a `|`.

Is there a way to match `myString/blah1` or `yourString.blah1` or `myString/blah2` etc.. using a regex against each line in a file?

There is a lot of code, so I just posted what seemed relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression that you are looking to build should be as follows:

```
myString/(?:\Qblah1\E|\Qblah2\E)
```

You need to wrap the strings `blah1`, `blah2`, etc. in `\Q` - `\E` in case the strings contain *regex metacharacters*. To fix the addition of leading `|` use a boolean variable that indicates if this is the first iteration through the loop or not:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean isFirst = true;
for(String word : stringList) {
    if (!isFirst) {
        sb.append('|');
    } else {
        isFirst = false;
    }
    sb.append("\\Q");
    sb.append(word);
    sb.append("\\E");
}
String regex = "myString/" + "(?:" + sb + ")";
```

Comment: Should be noted that `\Q...\E` is Java 6+ only

Comment: @fge That's strange: Oracle's docs mention `\Q`...`\E` in [Javadocs for `Pattern` of 1.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can you explain the `?:` in the regex?

Comment: @nkon `(?:regex)` makes `regex` a non-capturing group. You need a group to avoid adding `myString/` multiple times. Unless you want to retrieve the value matched by `regex`, you can use `?:` to make the group non-capturing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic problem is that your pattern (ignoring the trailing | problem) is something like

```
(myString/|yourString.)blah1|blah2|blah3
```

which will match one of these

```
myString/blah1
yourString.blah1
blah2
blah3
```

That's how the operator precedence works in regexes.  You need an extra set of parentheses around the lines from the file (plus see the other answers about \Q..\E and avoiding the bar at the end of the string).